# Display data from one workbook depending on mapping in a second workbook

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have really hit a wall here, and hope someone with a bit more excel-knowledge than myself will be able to point me in the right direction.
Have been stuck with this issues for quite some time now, and my Google-skills haven't been able to point me to a solution so far. I haven't been able to find it covered elsewhere, however, if it is, please point me in the direction.

I have 3 different workbooks.

- RAW source document

[image: RAW source document]

- Mapping document

[image: Mapping document]

- Destination document

[image: Destination document]

I am looking to pull the data from the source document to the destination document based on the mapping defined in the mapping document.

So something like

> if "Destination-document heading = mapping document destination"
>
> > lookup "mapping document source heading in RAW source document"
> >     and "display all data for the specific heading in destination document".`

I have tried with the following, however it does not seem to provide any results for me:

```
=if(vlookup(destinationdocA1;mappingdocA1:B4;2;0);vlookup(mappingdocA1;RAWdocA1:B4;1;0);"")
```

Comment: Will both `RAW` and `Destination` workbooks be open at the same time?

Comment: They could be. They will most likely be open at the same time. Will it make a difference if both books are open or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume I have three workbooks as follows:

```
Source.xlsx       - has a table of data starting in `A1` (as per screenshot)
Destination.xlsx  - has column headers starting in `A1` (as per screenshot)
Mapping.xlsx      - has mapping table with destination (but see below)
```

You need to reverse the order of the columns in `Mapping` to allow `VLOOKUP` to work:

```
Destination     Source
name_v          name
country_v       country
category_v      category
```

In the range `A2` in the `Destination` workbook add this formula:

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("[Source.xlsx]Sheet1!", ADDRESS(ROW(),MATCH(VLOOKUP(A$1,[Mapping.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$B$4,2,FALSE),[Source.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$1:$C$1,0))))
```

Drag this formula across all your cells to get the results you want.

In simple terms we are trying to find a row and column reference to the `Source` workbook to find the correct data value. We can then leverage `ADDRESS` and `INDIRECT` to display it in the `Destination` workbook.

A worked example using you screenshots. In cell A2 we want the result `LEGO`:

```
> Step 1 - map the column header (e.g. what does name_v correspond to?)
VLOOKUP(A$1,[Mapping.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$B$4,2,FALSE) = "name"

> Step 2 - get the column number for "name" in the source workbook
MATCH("name",[Source.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$1:$C$1,0) = 1

> Step 3 - get the row number (assumes both tables in Source and Dest start on same row)
ROW() = 2

> Step 4 - put together the address reference
ADDRESS(2, 1)  // corresponds to Range("A2")

> Step 5 - finally reference the Source workbook to pull back the correct value
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("[Source.xlsx]Sheet1!", ADDRESS(2, 1)) = "LEGO"
```

Comment: Thank you for a very elaborate explanation. I have tried to follow the setup you have created however when executing it I encounter some issues. In the destination file; for headings with no equivalent mapping it returns an #N/A which I assume is to be expected. However the issue is for the headings which do have an equivalent mapping, they return a #REF error. I have gone through the formula several times and cannot seem to see where I mess up.

Comment: I am using the following script: =INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("Raw Source!"; ADDRESS(ROW();MATCH(VLOOKUP(A$1;'[Mapping.xlsx]Mapping'!$A$2:B$858;2;FALSE);'Raw Source'!$A$1:$AFY$1;0)))) 
Please note that I am working on a European version of Excel, which I believe changes the format from being comma to semi-colon separated. For simplicity I have also combined to have both the destination and raw in the same workbook (but different tabs).

Comment: For `#REF` errors check for white space etc. e.g. use `TRIM()`. For `#N/A` you can modify the formula to handle them e.g. `IF(NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP...`

Comment: I have tried to add the `TRIM()` function, however it still provides a `#REF` error. It currently looks like this: `=IFNA(TRIM(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("Raw Source!"; ADDRESS(ROW();MATCH(VLOOKUP(A$1;'[ClinicalVault.eTMF.Mapping (v0.04).xlsx]Mapping'!$A$2:B$858;2;FALSE);'Raw Source'!$A$1:$AFY$1;0)))));"")` Should the trim function be added later? As it is now the trim function could remove the deliberate space before `ADDRESS()`?

Comment: I am wondering if it has an impact on the function you have suggested that the source and destination sheets does not have the same structure. Meaning that the source sheet have many more headings than the destination sheet. Plus, the headings do not fall 1-to-1, so it could be that the headings go a,b,c in source but a,c,b in destination.

Comment: You should use `TRIM()` on the lookup value. It may be worth manually using `TRIM()` on all your headers to be sure there are no leading / trailing characters etc. The 1-to-1 mapping should not matter as the code looks for a match and then gets the correct column.

Comment: I have taken it step by step to verify each function inside the string of functions. Every function until `INDIRECT()` seems to provide what we would expect. If I take it like this `CONCATENATE("Raw Source!"; ADDRESS(ROW();MATCH(VLOOKUP(DH$1;'[Mapping.xlsx]Mapping'!$A$2:DI$858;2;FALSE);'Raw Source'!$A$1:$AFY$1;0)))` it returns `Raw Source!$B$8`, which is the correct reference to where it should pull the data from.

Comment: I finally got it working - Thank you very much for your help. I somehow had missed `' '` around the reference to the source sheet in the `CONCATENATE()` function. Final solution was: `=IFNA(TRIM(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'Raw Source'!"; ADDRESS(ROW(); MATCH(TRIM(VLOOKUP(A$1;'[Mapping.xlsx]Mapping'!$A$2:$B$858;2;FALSE));'Raw Source'!$A$1:$AFY$1;0)))));"")`. The extra `TRIM()` function is there to remove any 0's i would get if the heading had a mapping to source but the row had no content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HLOOKUP` with `MATCH` like:

```
=HLOOKUP($A$7,$A$1:$C$4,MATCH(A2,$A$1:$A$4,0),0)
```

[image]

Comment: Does this assume that the headings in both RAW Source and Destination have the same structure? I will have to be able to display the data based on the mapping. This is due to the headings not necessarily having the same structure in the two documents.